# Margin under an input field with Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, input

whatever I try, I can't get the margin under the input fields under a certain value. It should work for this:

```
input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And it works for `50px` for example but I can't get below a certain margin. Also tried it with `!important` but that didn't help aswell.

Those styles are getting applied. Disabling them doesn't change the margin unfortunately.

```
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #555555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    opacity: 1;
}
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group string optional house_name">
     <label class="string optional control-label" for="house_name">Name</label>
     <input id="house_name" class="string optional form-control" type="text" value="new house" name="house[name]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group select optional house_region">
      <label class="select optional control-label" for="house_region_id">Region</label>
      <select id="house_region_id" class="select optional form-control" name="house[region_id]">
        <option value="">Wähle eine Region</option>
        <option value="1">Provence-Alpes-Côte d’Azur in Frankreich</option>
        <option value="2">Midi-Pyrenäen in Frankreich</option>
        <option value="3">Lombardei in Italien</option>
        <option value="4">Andalusien in Spanien</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group string optional house_htype">
      <label class="string optional control-label" for="house_htype">Typ</label>
      <input id="house_htype" class="string optional form-control" type="text" placeholder="Typ" name="house[htype]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see in all of your styles that single style - `input{margin-bottom: 5px}` ?

Comment: Oh yea my bad this CSS was from my select_field. I'll change it right now.

Comment: Can you also post your markup?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by markup.

Comment: Part of your HTML (snippet) where you're using those styles. It would be also good to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Well, using `!important` should work - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vsq2xw6/). However, using `!important` isn't the best solution. You can modify the selector to be more [specific](http://specificity.keegan.st/) containing its parent like `.col-md-4 input {}`, which is a better solution - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vsq2xw6/1/)

Comment: Hmm, seems like you didn't understand me right. In your example there is no margin on the bottom of the field as long as you don't add it yourself. In my application there is a big margin and I want it gone but I can't figure out what excactly is causing the margin. I bet it has something to do with bootstrap. Probably the `*::after` part of the css.

Comment: Using `margin-bottom: of -20px;` works now but it's not very clean to put it everywhere in my application because it happens quite often that bootstrap is adding extra margins.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put a div around your input and give that the margin?

Comment: Tried it. Didn't change anything though. I just realized that I have the same problem for my bootstrap taps. Also looks like the margin is the same.